# jQuery - remove grandparent class with all subclasses

Tags: jquery

I have code like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label> Text </label>                                       
      <input type="text" class="required" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label> Text 2</label>                                       
      <input type="text" class="required" name="something else" id="something else">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Problem is:
how to remove "row" with all sub classes inside if grandchild has unique id or name?
On my jQuery "change" event I have unique "name" of grandchild of row I need to remove, so I just need to find "row" witch contains unique "name".
For example, my jQuery events says that "name" I need to remove is "email". So, output should looks like this:

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
       <label> Text 2</label>                                       
       <input type="text" class="required" name="something else" id="something else">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I've tried something like this but nothing happens :

```
var element = $('.container').children(".row.col-md-12.input[name=this.name]");
    if( element.text() === $this.text())
            element.parent().parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change:

```
var element = $('.container').children(".row.col-md-12.input[name=this.name]");
```

To:

```
var element = $('.container').find(".row .col-md-12 input[name='"+ this.name +"']");
```

Assuming `this.name` is a variable with correct value.

**EDIT:**

Take a look at this example, maybe you have doing it wrong. The input don't have text, but a value, so the following code show you a good start to understand:

```
var name = 'email';
var value = 'value';

var element = $('.container').find(".row .col-md-12 input[name='"+ name +"']");
if(element.val() === value){
    element.parent().parent().remove();
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/70yksx6y/1/

Comment: Please see my EDIT, I prepare a working example for you to show how it should be.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find the node for the Input. You can do this with these two alternatives, find your best way.

```
var element = $('.container').find('input[name=email]');
```

Or

```
var element = $('input[name=email');
```

*Replace email with a dynamically expression but be sure you're focusing the input right*.

When you get the element you can go into his parents with

```
var parentElement = element.closest('.row');
```

And then remove it with `parentElement.remove();`

According to jQuery documentation:

**.closest():** For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.